# Change plotBands options after chart creation

Tags: highcharts

Can you in plotBands use "wildcards" og min/max values for to/from value?

Like here http://jsfiddle.net/CBE9R/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {        

            tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
             plotBands: [{ 
                color: 'green',
                from: 150,
                to: ''
                },{ 
                color: 'red',
                from: '',
                to: '150'
                }]
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }]
    });
});
```

Without knowing the min/max values of the chart is there a way to set for instance red from bottom to 150 and from 150 to top as green ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using API after chart is rendered:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
var extremes = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
var maxY = extremes.max;
var minY = extremes.min;

chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            color: 'green',
            from: 150,
            to: maxY
});
chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            color: 'red',
            from: minY,
            to: '150'
});
```

Function `getExtremes()` returns current extremes for the axis (dataMax, dataMin, max and min axis value). And those values are used to set proper bands. Note: additional check should be done if hardcoded value (150) is between minY and maxY.

See updated [example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBE9R/2/).

Comment: I think this is only *creating* (rather than changing) plot bands after the chart has been created.

Comment: Yea... the question asked was whether you could get and then edit an existing plot band. This accepted answer doesn't tell you how to do that at all.